tf.data.Dataset.shuffle() vs shuffle during tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets
I have plenty of tf.data.Dataset and want to shuffle the contents during each epoch. I load them as follows:
ds = tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets(datasets, stop_on_empty_dataset=False, rerandomize_each_iteration=True)

For my understanding, this loads the data in random order (cf. sample_from_datasets).
Should I still apply ds.shuffle(buffer_size, reshuffle_each_iteration=True) afterwards or is the above loading function fine for randomization of inputs?
What is best practice?

The example in your link already answers your question with Samples elements at random and also One possible outcome of elements in sample_dataset is:, which means that the outcome is not fixed and in the example it is also already randomized. Calling ds.shuffle on it is not necessary.
